# Filing in C / add data

Tags: c, file-io

I am trying to make random acces filing program it is just for starting. I have problem about filing addData function is not working correct when I look biodata.txt there are so many strange characters. I am trying to file with structure.

```
  #include <stdio.h>
    #include <conio.h>

    struct biodata{
           int recno,age;
           char name[20],sex;
           float salary;
    }obj;


    int main(){
         void addData(void);

         void showRecord(void);
          char choice;

         while(1){



          printf("\n\n*****CHOOSE YOUR CHOICE*****\n");
          printf("1) ADD DATA\n");

          printf("2) SHOW RECORD\n");

          printf("Enter your choice : ");

          choice = getche();
          switch(choice){
             case '1' :   //call add data
                    addData();
                    break;

             case '2' :  //call show record
                    showRecord();
                    break;


          }
         }

    }


    //Adding Record to File
    void addData(){
         FILE *fp;

         fp = fopen("biodata.txt","a+t");

         printf("\n*****ADDING DATA*****\n");
         printf("\nEnter Record No : ");
         scanf("%d",&obj.recno);
         printf("Enter Name : ");

         scanf("%s",&obj.name);
         printf("Enter age : ");
         scanf("%d",&obj.age);

         printf("Enter Sex : ");
         scanf("%c",&obj.sex);
         printf("Enter Salary : ");
         scanf("%f",&obj.salary);
     fseek(fp,(obj.recno-1)*sizeof(obj),SEEK_SET);
    fwrite(&obj,sizeof(obj),1,fp);

         fclose(fp);
    }

    void showRecord(){
         FILE *fp;
         struct biodata obj;
         int rec;
         long pos;
         fp = fopen("biodata.txt","r");

         printf("\n*****SHOWING SPECIFIC RECORD*****\n");
         printf("\nEnter Record No : ");
         scanf("%d",&rec);
         pos = rec * sizeof(obj);
         fseek(fp,pos,SEEK_SET);
         if(feof(fp)==0)
        printf("\n\nNO DATA FOUND\n");
         else{
         fscanf(fp,"%d %s %d %c %f",&obj.recno,obj.name,&obj.age,&obj.sex,&obj.salary);
         printf("\n\n\tRecord No :  %d\n",obj.recno);
         printf("\tName : %s\n",obj.name);
         printf("\tAge  : %d\n",obj.age);
         printf("\tSex  : %c\n",obj.sex);
         printf("\tSalary : %f\n",obj.salary);
         }
         getch();
         fclose(fp);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting strange characters in biodata.txt is that you're using `fwrite()`, which does *binary stream output*, in the function `addData()` to output stuff you intend to interpret as text. You would want to use something like `fprintf()` instead.

To be a bit more specific, the weird characters are most likely the members of type `int` and `float` of the structure you're outputting - the string `"12345"` and the integer with value `12345` do not have the same binary representation, and the `fscanf(fp, "%d %s %d %c %f", ...)` expects the former (for example, the integer `12345` is represented as the textual string `"12345"`), while `addData()` outputs the binary integer directly, with no conversion taking place. So, in short, you need to use a function such as `fprintf()` to convert the integers and floats into the appropriate textual representation.